Sink intake copper tubing is 1/16" more narrow than the angle stop valve fittings
For the hot (left) and cold (right) intakes the new angle stop valves have made different decisions on whether they want to stay in place or not. The hot/left feels tight and I was able to tighten with a wrench as desired.  The cold/right does not "bite" at all - even given the ferrule is in place beneath the nut and between the nut and the valve thread.  Thread sealant was added as well: but that made no difference and in any case is not intended for structural strength but only to seal any tiny cracks in the fit.

Here is a top-down view of the non-fast/slipping fitting. We can see that the ferrule, nut, and threads are all ready to "try" to do their job. However they are defeated out of the gate by the slightly too narrow copper pipe underneath them: they try to grab to air instead of the pipe:

Upon measuring the angle stop's ferrule: 5/8 inch inner diameter. Instead the copper pipe - which is 1970's vintage - is 9/16 inner diameter. That 1/16 disparity allows more than plenty of slippage.
What are my options here? Are there any ways to do the following:

some kind of very thin copper shim for the pipe fitting?
a different ferrule (but yet still needs to provide a tight seal with the angle stop valve
some paste on material that fills space permanently?

Or do I need to dump the current approach and do something similar to one of the following:
A. Get a shark bite/pex/pvc or similar angle stop valve
B. [Most radical]: replace the last section of copper with pex and then do A.

I’m grasping at straws, but is there any chance that you just need to get the ferrule closer to the open end of the pipe and then crank on the wrenches?

@AloysiusDefenestrate.  For removing the old ferrules I really cranked on the wrenches - to the point of breaking one remover and bending the twist bar of the second. But for installing the new ferrule here there's nothing to crank on:  it slips. We need the ferrule to "catch" first.  I added pipe thread tape - which essentially shims the ferrule and it's holding now. But I might come back at some point to completely replace these lines.

C. sweat a threaded adapter on and use a threaded stop valve that fits the adapter.  (But A is really the easy button here.)

@Huesmann. Yes (c) is actually the first option that came to mind. But I already have the non-threaded stop valves and do not want to return them. Unfortunately the shark bites that I have are for 3/4" pipe so I'd have to get new ones of those as well ($$). No happy /easy path here given the materials on hand.

My experience with plumbing is that it’s usually 3 trips to the store: #1 to get what you think you need, #2 to get what you actually needed, and #3 to replace what broke while you were doing the work. So I wouldn’t feel bad about a return visit to get threaded copper and a different stop.

@AloysiusDefenestrate. That's a good list!  I'm instead doing most of it by amazon, but the concept still applies.

If you go to the store for threaded adapters, remember to bring the valves to confirm fit, or you may have to make yet another trip!

The OD of 1/2" trade size copper pipe has not changed over the decades.
Your copper pipe stubs look really clean, how did you clean them up?  I'm thinking there is the possibility of overzealous cleaning with sandpaper or something that reduced the OD of the copper pipe to the point that the ferrule doesn't grab anymore.
If that's the case, you could try a sharkbite or try sweating a union on there to see if that will salvage it.  Sharkbites work by using an o-ring inside, so perhaps that o-ring can take up the extra space.  Or sweating a union, perhaps the solder can take up the extra space.  If neither of those work, then you may have to cut the pipe back to a spot that still has the full OD.

I just used the standard fare emery cloth and did not overdo it.  That's the real diameter of the pipe. An additional data point is that the section closest to the wall was already clean so I did not need to touch it: and that section is "even" with the ferrule-removed portion that did need the cleaning.

By the way the original ferrule is a hair narrower as well: it fitted snugly. It really is a different measurement of pipe/fittings.   I even looked for evidence of crimping of the ferrule but it looked normally shaped.  It's hard to understand.

That's really surprising, pipe diameters are well controlled during manufacturing.  I guess that's some odd size that isn't normally used for water supply in North America?

It's an old house that's been abused. Any questions about the original materials and/or what has been done to them are fair game.  It is challenging because I'm just learning how to do these things and they seldom work "as advertised" on the youtube's. I have to figure out not just how to do the work the right way but also how to deal with it when it was already done some other way [and does not accept standard materials, tools , and practices.]. In this case the whole assembly just slips: that's not supposed to happen.
